# How can i insert return value to mysql database in python?

Tags: python, mysql

i try to make a project for my pi. I want to read temperature and insert the temperature value to my database. i can read temperature but i can not insert it to my database. Can some one tell me where is my mistake? Thanks for your help. Best wishes :)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests
import hashlib
import time
import MySQLdb
#Dont forget to fill in PASSWORD and URL TO saveTemp (twice) in this file

sensorids = ["28-00042d99c9ff", "28-00042d99c9ff"]
avgtemperatures = []
for sensor in range(len(sensorids)):
    temperatures = []
    for polltime in range(0,3):
            text = '';
            while text.split("\n")[0].find("YES") == -1:
                    # Open the file that we viewed earlier so that python can see what          is in it. Replace the serial number as before.
                    tfile = open("/sys/bus/w1/devices/"+ sensorids[sensor] +"/w1_slave")
                    # Read all of the text in the file.
                    text = tfile.read()
                    # Close the file now that the text has been read.
                    tfile.close()
                    time.sleep(1)

            # Split the text with new lines (\n) and select the second line.
            secondline = text.split("\n")[1]
            # Split the line into words, referring to the spaces, and select the 10th word (counting from 0).
            temperaturedata = secondline.split(" ")[9]
            # The first two characters are "t=", so get rid of those and convert the temperature from a string to a number.
            temperature = float(temperaturedata[2:])
            # Put the decimal point in the right place and display it.
            temperatures.append(temperature / 1000 )

    avgtemperatures.append(sum(temperatures) / float(len(temperatures)))

print avgtemperatures[0]
print avgtemperatures[1]



# Open database connection
db = MySQLdb.connect("my db-ip", "my user name", "my pass", "my db name" )

# prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
cursor = db.cursor()

# Prepare SQL query to INSERT a record into the database.
sql = "INSERT INTO temps(temp1,temp2) VALUES (avgtemperatures[0], avgtemperatures[1])" 
try:
   # Execute the SQL command
   cursor.execute(sql)
   # Commit your changes in the database
   db.commit()
except:
   # Rollback in case there is any error
   db.rollback()

# disconnect from server
db.close()
```

Comment: what error do you get when you run this?

Comment: This is error message my friend.                         temper.py:50: Warning: Data truncated for column 'temp1 at row 1 cursor.execute(sql)                                          temper.py:50: Warning: Data truncated for column 'temp2 at row 1 cursor.execute(sql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the 'warnings' are the only errors -- then it's just a matter of converting from the python types to the SQL database's column types. Chances are, your python types are set with a higher level of precision than the columns in the table. This is what it means by 'truncated'. Data is getting chopped off. What are your table's column types?

If you plan on doing a lot of database stuff I would recommend SQL Alchemy or another object-relational mapper that can help you avoid small inconsistencies like this.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer my friend. My table data types are temp1 float, temp2 float , id int.

Comment: i couldn't fix problem :( i cant understand why my code is not runing. It look like correct.

Comment: Perhaps you should try setting the columns to DECIMAL instead of float.